# How to set column default value to today's date in SQL using XML

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, date

I want to add a column to one of my SQL schema's tables.

I have tried the following:

```
<property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql"/>

        <changeSet author="Trey Collier" id="SCHEJ-376">
            <addColumn tableName="schedule">
                <column name="dateLastPublished" type="DATETIME" defaultValueDate="${now}">
                    <constraints nullable="false" />
                </column>
            </addColumn>
        </changeSet>
```

However, this inserts the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmm:ss`, but I only want the `YYYY-MM-DD` part of it. How can I change my current XML code to make this happen? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `defaultValueDate="${now}"` with `defaultValueDate="(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))"` and `type="DATETIME"` with `type="DATE"`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!